Labour saving technological change VS Capital saving technological change
I have been learning about technological change in relation with production functions(cobb Douglas) and isoquants and I'm very confused as the explanations can be somewhat vague and not clear enough.
Query 1 ) When we have capital-saving technological change otherwise known as labour augmenting or harrod neutral, we say that compared to capital .... labour has become more efficient or productive therefore less labour is needed for a given level of capital to produce the same quantity. One of the ways in which we can show this is if we had a fixed ratio of inputs and for a fixed level of quantity the MRTS for the isoquant of the new production function will be steeper, which makes sense to me.
However, what confused me was when they showed this harrod neutral representation of it

You can see here that both curves represent the same output level, however, I am not sure why they didn't just draw a line from the origin (a fixed ratio of inputs) and then find the MRTS of the points where the curves meet the line and you would see that MRTS gets steeper( this is what they do for hicks natural except that MRTS stays the same).
Let's indulge for a second this picture's way of showing it where you can see from the horizontal line for a fixed capital level less labour is needed to make the same output which makes sense as that's the argument for capital-saving tech change.
What confused me is that for this very same picture, I draw a vertical line for a given point at L, which then intersects the curve twice, we witness that for a fixed level of labour, less capital is needed (the argument for solow neutral) so we are also saying that capital has become more effective than labour ie capital saving.
So then what's the point of this representation if you can make both arguments with it anyway, I can't clearly see here what mathematically separates the two tech changes.
Query 2 ) Regarding labour-saving tech change(capital becomes more effective) and labour-saving tech change(capital becomes more effective). There is an extract in my textbook where it says the complete opposite of what I have described here .

So we can also see here they say that for labour saving when they say how the introduction of bar codes caused the average product of labour to increase, I'm assuming they are making the argument that labour saving tech change caused labour to become more efficient (contradictory to the solow model/capital saving where they say capital has become more efficient in comparison to labour).
Using average product per worker in my opinion is stupid to illustrate this in the first place because whether the technological progress positively affected one input more than the other, the average quantity would increase either way for both inputs because I'm assuming more output can be made with the exact same combination of inputs.
Please could someone explain to me what on earth is going on, and why everyone is saying contradictory things, everyone is using different terms to describe the same thing solow deepening saving etc that I feel I confused the terminology.
